# is it possible to limit parallel tests in xcuitest?

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

Im doing uitest, in test plan theres 'execute in parallel (if possible)' option. However this launches 5 simulator in my case, consuming all 32gb of ram (and some swap) and tests fails for unknown reasons, is it possible to limit maximum number of launched simulator clones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the number in Xcode's General Preferences. The automatic number is frequently flaky.

[image: screenshot of preferences]